# How are Public APIs made Cross Domain for All Browsers?

Tags: javascript, web-services, api

For example, if Twitter's API allowed Puts and Posts (I'm not sure if it does), do they simply enable CORS on their end?

But IE 9 and lower do not handle CORS.

So can these browsers simply not use websites that directly call the twitter API from JS?

Comment: Generally the solution is to use JSONP for browsers that don't support CORS

Comment: @RunscopeAPITools JSONP doesn't allow POSTS and PUTS, it is GET only.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I understand that that would work... but that seems like such a hack...  That's really how people put up with IE?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Actually, John, that doesn't work for me, because the request length I need to use in my GET is longer than that which is capable of going into URL encoding for a GET.  I need to use a POST body.

Comment: Generally, if you can't just use `JSONP` with `GET`-only and need to support browsers where `CORS` is unavailable, you're left with using a same-origin proxy -- `browser <=> //yourdomain.com/twitter/... <=> //twitter.com/....`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski So just to make sure I'm understanding you correctly, you're saying I would create a second website that isn't cross domain, POST to that for IE, then use server side code to post to the actual API?

Comment: @RobertChrist The proxy script/route should be on the same server that serves up the page, JavaScript, etc.

Comment: so if I had robertchrist.com, and I needed to POST to twitter, then I would write robertchrist.com/api/, my logical flow would be:

JS - 'Am I in IE?'  JS - 'If Yes, POST to robertchrist.com/api.'  Server - 'I receive a POST from robertchrist.com/api.'  Server -      'Send a POST to twitter with CORS.'  Server - 'Receive a POST response from Twitter.'  Server - Send a response via robertchrist.com/api  JS - Receive a response from robertchrist.com/api

Comment: What about an `XDomainRequest` for IE8?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy You're right, this is what I ended up figuring out after more research.  If you write an answer to this question, I'll mark it as correct.  For completeness, you should include a link to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx  and https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the workarounds for CORS not being supported by `XMLHttpRequest` in IE9 and lower is Microsoft's very own proprietary [`XDomainRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). While it is similar in some respects to `XMLHttpRequest`, it has quite a few limitations on its capabilities. Some of these include ([source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx)):

- Only `GET` and `POST` requests are permitted (i.e. no `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc.)
- Only the HTTP and HTTPS protocols can be used (not a major issue most of the time)
- Request must still be to the same protocol scheme, even if correct cross-origin headers are set (i.e HTTP -> HTTPS is not permitted, and vice versa)
- No request headers can be modified, nor can new headers be set
- The `Content-Type` header is not set by IE
- No cookies will be sent with the request
- If your site is on an intranet, it won't be able to access internet resources

Due to `XMLHttpRequest` being the preferred method of doing cross-origin requests, libraries such as jQuery do not include support for `XDomainRequest` by default (that has been [requested and declined](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283), however there are numerous alternative projects out there that provide this functionality, such as:

- [jQuery CORS plugin](https://github.com/Ovea/cors)
- [Cross-Domain AJAX for IE8](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest)
- [XDomain](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain) (although this just replaces the native XMLHttpRequest constructor with a cross-browser compatible version)

Another alternative, if these limitations happen to be too much, is to setup a proxy on your server between the client and the cross-origin site (of course, this should only be done when needed, as this would use up your server's bandwidth and data usage).